# Extract unicode text from dump file

Tags: debugging, windbg

I had a program freeze (sql developer specifically) that had some unsaved files in it.  I used sysinternal's process explorer to create a dump file before killing the process.  I really only lost a couple of hours of work but I thought it would be a good learning experience to see what I could extract from the dump file.  So far I've downloaded and ran windbg and have found my text with:

```
s -u 0x00000000 L?0xffffffff "text I know exists in my file"
```

From there I got the relevent memory addresses and could view the text in the memory window along with much of the file.  However, from here I'm a bit stuck.  I know I could use the du command to dump text but what sort of strategy should I use to determine the begin and end range.  This is a 1 Gig dump so I'm nevervous to dump 0x00000000 to 0xffffffff as I wouldn't have text file that most editors could open.  Is there a way to just dump user memory or non-code memory, etc?  It doesn't have to be perfect by any means.  I was content just opening the dump file in textpad, but unicode data doesn't show up, only the occational ascii (presumably because textpad cant detect the type or because it's a 64 bit dump).

Comment: having read your post closer you are looking for a programmatic method to search through a memory region for your string and to dump the addresses?

Comment: No, not programmatic.  I would consider this purely a debugging exercise.  I'm hoping to learn how to navigate the dump file a little better by accomplishing this task.

Comment: So you are looking for a strategy to search your process memory space for a string? I can't think immediately of an effective strategy other than only searching the process heap only, you should be able to determine this by looking at the `!address` output and seeing which heap increases, and then just search those heaps. The other possibility is to determine the size of the string and search for just those allocations that match that size.

Comment: You could also try the strings.exe utility from sysinternals (now MS) and just redirect all the output (unicode and ascii) to a text file. Then search the text file (or just eye-ball it) for what you're looking for.

Comment: @Marc, while your method doesn't exactly teach me much about windbg, it absolutely satisfies the OP.  Would you like to answer formally so I can give you credit?

Comment: FYI, doing my search as I described earlier worked reasonably well.  I would find the text and then do a .writemem c:\myfile 0x2d5054a8 L?100000  I found did the dump with an earlier address I could eventually find the top of the file.  Overshooting caused textpad to garble things a bit (presumably because it couldn't figure out the encoding from the first couple of bytes), but it let me see what the file started with which would let me rerun the search for that text and get the exact starting point, leaving me with reasonably clean files.  Nothing compared to strings.exe though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could also try the strings.exe utility from sysinternals (now MS) and just redirect all the output (unicode and ascii) to a text file. Then search the text file (or just eye-ball it) for what you're looking for.

Comment: While not exactly the debugging example I was looking for, this is dead on relative to the title.  I guess windbg will have to wait for later because strings.exe rescued my lost work :).